# New line character not being replaced even after trying many methods

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I cannot get this to replicate outside of this file, since if I try it on a string myself it works, but for some reason not in my dataframe.

I just want to get rid of the '\n' characters in my strings, but its not working, as seen below.

[image]

I've tried the following, with no success

```
UseCaseMethodsCols.apply(lambda x: ' ' if '\n' in x else x)
UseCaseMethodsCols = UseCaseMethodsCols.replace(r'\n', ' ').replace(r'\r', '')
```

Comment: If it's an actual newline you shouldn't use a raw string as `r'\n'` is a \ followed by an `n`

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `regex=True` to the `replace` calls:

```py
UseCaseMethodsCols = UseCaseMethodsCols.replace(r'\n', ' ', regex=True)
```